# rsyncing from ext3 on mac: file has vanished

Tags: osx, rsync, fuse, hfs+

I am on Os X and I am rsyncing from a `ext3` volume (that I read with `osxfuse 2.6.2`) to a `HFS+` volume. The data I am backupping are ~ `500GB`. Sometimes `rsync` gives the following message:

```
file has vanished: '/path/to/file'
```

if I check the file path I find that the file is listed there but then `no such file or directory`. I would think this is a problem of osxfuse. 
Sometimes if I run rsync again some more files are transferred, but I always get the same warning regarding other files.

I would think my backup is incomplete, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Those are intermediate files the system creates and removes (might be created before `rsync` started). The first `rsync` takes long, so that happens often between start and finish.

You would not miss anything vital (since it is gone anyway), but just do another `rsync -a <from> <to>` afterwards and that should run much faster, not giving the system much time to (create and) remove files during the `rsync`.

Comment: I have looked to the relevant path and they look like regular files, for example like files of scripting I have created in the past.

Comment: Are these removed on the source system? If on the destination system, it might be two `rsync`s competing. Have you tried rsync over `ssh` instead NFS?

Comment: the ext3 volume and the HFS volume are two external drives. I am transferring data from one drive to the other, and I am not changing anything on the source meanwhile. what I will do next is investigating what happens if I read the ext3 volume from linux

Comment: @simona I did not read HFS correctly, thought that was NFS therefor I suggested using rsync over ssh.